# Low poly hair animation with hair bones

Tags: animation, rigging, hair

So I've been trying to get the hair bones to work with the whole body. I got bones to deform some parts of the polygonal hair and these bones belong to the same body armature. However the problem is when I move the head bone, it deforms the mesh where the hair bones are. So I cannot move the head up and down without the hair going off the rails because of the hair bones.

I understand this is because the hair bones have deform, but I am not bending those hair bones, why is the hair deforming? Btw the hair is a separate mesh.  I want to be able to animate the hair, along with keeping the rotation/location same when the head is moving up and down. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is the weirdest solution. What Josh said got me going, checking more and more about parent/child relationship and he was right. But not exactly right.

I have a hair mesh, a body mesh, and one armature. My armature has the usual body bones, and little hair bones offsetting off the head bone that got weights around certain places in the hair mesh so now I can animate my poly hair if I want (Unity). The problem I was having was, as I moved the head bone, the hair mesh was parented to the armature so the hair mesh was moving fine, but so were the hair bones deforming the hair for some reason. I just couldn't get the hair to keep with its original position.

Then I saw the parenting stuff in the hair mesh properties and fiddled around - instead of parent Armature, I made the hair mesh's parent to be the body mesh object. And ODDLY, this fixed it. Now I can move my head and the hair mesh moves perfectly angled, AND I can move the hair bones to move the weighted portions of the hair mesh as I wanted. This is weird. But I am very happy with the results. Thank you Blender Stack Exchange. And thank YOU Josh.

Comment: There are always different methods to reach a desired behaviour, but I think you should clarify yourself the difference between moving an object (moving its origin, wich moves all vertices) and moving vertices only (leaving the origin untouched, often in the center of the world scene). This to avoid confusion and unexpected behaviours, expecially when exporting to another software. As a rule of thumb it's better to move vertices only -  with bones, shape keys, lattices - checking if the game engine can support all features you use.

Comment: I move only the bones not vertices. I am new to blender so maybe I am misunderstanding something. :) But I am certainly not moving vertices. I got the bone weights set to the hair portions i want to animate, like spiky polygonal hair. And I will clarify this, I am not "moving" those hair bones since they are only offsetting, I can only rotate them. Moving those bones seem to deform the mesh away from the body like stretching the mesh. But I can move the head bone , because it is connected by the bone to the neck.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a wrong Parent/Child relationship: hair bones should be child of the head bone (keep offset), so that when you move the head the hair follows. Then hair mesh should have no parent, except that of its bones (if some part of the hair should remain still you can weight thoose vertices to the head bone, or create a new hair bone that you'll not move in animation data).

Comment: When I try this, I made the hair bones into their own armature. Otherwise how do I give the hair mesh no parent and to the bones, if the hair bones have the head bone as a parent? The hair mesh does not move at all when it isn't parented to the headbone. Unless I am missing something?